# AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync throws error after upgrading Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory to 5.2.9

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I am trying to update the .NET Framework version of my company's app created from ASP.NET MVC 5 to 4.8 and also updated some old libraries including Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

After I upgrade Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory to 5.2.9

I am getting this error from the output console after successful login to Azure AD

```
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in mscorlib.dll
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in mscorlib.dll
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in mscorlib.dll
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in mscorlib.dll
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in mscorlib.dll
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in mscorlib.dll
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in mscorlib.dll
    Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException' in mscorlib.dll
```

when I try to capture the exception it throws with breakpoints, this is the message that I get

ex.Message:

```
AADSTS90002: Tenant '...' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID. Check with your subscription administrator.
Trace ID: ...
Correlation ID: ...
Timestamp: 2021-06-05 21:55:43Z
```

((Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException)ex).ErrorCode

```
invalid_request
```

ex.StackTrace:

```
   at Microsoft.Identity.Core.OAuth2.OAuthClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__18`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Core.OAuth2.OAuthClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__17`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<SendHttpMessageAsync>d__75.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<SendTokenRequestAsync>d__72.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<CheckAndAcquireTokenUsingBrokerAsync>d__62.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__60.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeCommonAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Accenture.GlobalOffice.WebAdmin.Web.MyAngularWebStartup.<OnAuthorizationCodeReceived>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\MyProject\MyProject.Web\MyAngularWebStartup.cs:line 178
```

Note: Replaced the sensitive infos with "..." due to company rules

Here is also the Startup.cs code where I am getting the error:

```
...

using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

...


[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(....MyAngularWebStartup))]

namespace ...
{
    public partial class MyAngularWebStartup
    {
        private static readonly string clientId = "clientId"; // A.K.A App ID
        private static readonly string clientSecret = "clientSecretKey";
        private static readonly string redirectUri = "https://localhost:44312/";
        private static readonly string tenant = "tenantId";
        private static readonly string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/v2.0";
        private static readonly string objectID = "objectID";
        private static readonly string graphResourceId = "graphResourceId";

        ...

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            // this is the line that throws errors when calling AuthorizationCodeReceived method of MyAngularWebStartup class
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,

                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                    }
                }
            );

            ...

        }

        ...

        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            if (context.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323"))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties(), OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        private static async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
        {
            try
            {
                var code = context.Code;

                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
                string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(objectID).Value;

                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));

                Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

                // I'm getting error in this line:
                AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, uri, credential, graphResourceId);
                context.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken = result.AccessToken;
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works when the app was in previous version

I'm not sure why it gives error now

Answer (score 0):

After very long time spent in it

I finally found the answer with this link

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows

The `authority` property of MyAngularWebStartup class is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/v2.0`

Which was changed in the latest version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory like this example:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId`

now, MyAngularWebStartup will be like:

```
...

using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

...


[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(....MyAngularWebStartup))]

namespace ...
{
    public partial class MyAngularWebStartup
    {
        private static readonly string clientId = "clientId"; // A.K.A. App ID
        private static readonly string clientSecret = "clientSecretKey";
        private static readonly string redirectUri = "https://localhost:44312/";
        private static readonly string tenant = "tenantId";
        private static readonly string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId";
        private static readonly string objectID = "objectID";
        private static readonly string graphResourceId = "graphResourceId";

        ...

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            // this is the line that throws errors when calling AuthorizationCodeReceived method of MyAngularWebStartup class
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,

                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                    }
                }
            );

            ...

        }

        ...

        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            if (context.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323"))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties(), OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        private static async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
        {
            try
            {
                var code = context.Code;

                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
                string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(objectID).Value;

                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));

                Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

                // I'm getting error in this line:
                AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, uri, credential, graphResourceId);
                context.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken = result.AccessToken;
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```